# UIPageControl value changed not firing

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have an issue with the `UIPageControl`. I simplified the issue for clarity below:

I put a button and a `UIPageControl` in my app with Interface builder and put the following in the code:

```
- (IBAction)tappedButton:(id)sender{
    self.pageControl.currentPage = 3;
    NSLog(@"Tapped Button");
}

- (IBAction)changePage:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"PAGE Changed!!!!");        
}
```

I attached the Value Changed action to the pageController via Interface Builder.

When I tap on the button, I see the output "Tapped Button" and the third dot is highlighted... but the `changePage` method is never called.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The changePage: method will only be called when the users request a change of page using the UIPageControl. It won't be called when the user taps the button. If you want to call the changePage: method when the button is pressed called it explicitly:

```
 [self changePage: nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

`UIPageControl` doesn't actually change pages for you. You have to write that code, inresponse to the valueChanged event. So, you want to connect that event of your UIPageControl object to your output (`tappedButton:` I guess), and then call your `changePage:` method to actually change the UI. Does that help?

There are some example projects referenced from the Apple docs that use UIScrollView and UIPageControl together. Check 'em out.